# Accessing member variable in Python?

Tags: python, class, oop, member

I have recently started learning python (coming from C++ background), but I could not understand how should I access the member variable (`nonce`) and use it in the second function called `def mine_block()`.Aren't all members of the class Block publicly available from everywhere?

```
class Block:
    '''
    Дефинираме ф-я , която създава
    променливите като членове на класа Block
    '''
    def _init_(self,prevHash,index,nonce,data,hash,time):
        self.prevHash = prevHash
        self.index = index
        self.nonce = nonce
        self.data = data
        self.hash = hash
        self.time = time

    def get_hash(self):
        print(self.hash)

    def mine_block(self,difficulty):
        arr = []
        for i in range(difficulty):
            arr[i] = '0'
        arr[difficulty] = '\0'
        str = arr
    while True:
        '''
        here I receive an error
        unresolved referene nonce
        '''
        nonce++
```

Comment: Your `while` loop is not intended to be part of the method. You also need `self.nonce`. `++` won't work either; `self.nonce += 1` instead.

Comment: It's just `self.nonce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to class attributes within the class methods you need pass the object itself into the methods with the keyword `self`. Then you can access other class methods and the class attributes with `self.foo`.

Also, the `while True` loop should not be indented at root level within the class. Last, the `foo++` C-style is not correct in Pyhton, it should be `foo += 1`

Answer (score 1):

In Python all instance members are publicly available through the class instance which is passed to class methods as `self`. Hence you should use `self.nonce`.

Besides, in Python be careful with indentation. Your mine_block method should look like:

```py
def mine_block(self,difficulty):
    ...
    str = arr
    while True:
        self.nonce += 1
```